# react-router Links based on current route

Tags: javascript, react-router, flux

I have the following route config where there is a component ShowObj and in it multiple tabs showing different aspects of an object.

```
<Route path={“/obj/:id"} component={ShowObj}>
    <Route path={“tab1”} component={Tab1} />
    <Route path={“tab2”} component={Tab2} />
    <IndexRoute component={Tab1} />
</Route>
```

At the top, in my ShowObj component, I want to render buttons to go to the next/prev obj. When doing that I want to keep the current tab rather than going to the default one. I.e., if I'm currently on obj XXX in tab2 (path "/obj/XXX/tab2") and I go to object YYY, I want to remain on same tab (path "/obj/YYY/tab2").

Since the router is already making the selection I was hoping there is a way that in my ShowObj I can somehow know indeed which tab is selected. I tried adding a prop to the route itself like in:

```
<Route path={“tab1”} component={Tab1} currentTab="tab1"/>
```

but it only seems to be available in Tab1 and not in ShowObj.

Two solutions I could think of:

1. Change my routes to make the tab also a param
2. Use the router transition hook to set (global) state of the tab I'm currently in and use that state when rendering (or clicking) those buttons.

Is there any simpler way? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest u to get current location from redux-react-router, mobx-react-router or similar libraries that provide current router. Or u can pass current location into context and get it from there